# Ошибка при запросе xmlhttprequest

Tags: php, javascript, json, http

Добрый день! Наткнулся на проблему.
Суть ее в следующем:

Есть C1 через который добавляются товары в CSV файл, где мирно себе хранятся.
Есть скрипт который обрабатывает запросы и выводит информацию из CSV файла на сайт. После определенного промежутка времени перестал работать раздел с этими товарами. Выдает ошибку. Прошлый кодер не указал ошибку при функции exit, и мне приходится искать ее самому.

Есть вот такой код, проверяющий запросы от умников.

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest'){
exit(Error);
}
```

Почему не проходит запрос и выдает ошибку? Заранее благодарю за любой ответ!

Comment: C1 это, наверное, 1С? Покажите кусочек кода, который отправляет запросы на сайт

Comment: Также посмотрите что за заголовки приходят при запросах (сниффером или просто выводом содержимого массива $_SERVER в файл)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-хорошему, этот код можно спокойно выбросить.
От "умников" он все равно никак не защитит, так что смысла в нем ноль.

Ну а не работает он из-за того, что в какой-то момент перестал передаваться заголовок `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`. Поскольку эта неправильная проверка реагирует только на его наличие, но не на содержание.

Учитывая, что и раньше этот код ничего не проверял, то проще всего будет от него избавиться.

Comment: Спасибо за совет!